# Angular 5 Firebase push object with "new" key word vs Object literal

Tags: angular, firebase

When sending data to firebase database. I first tried push an object created by "new" key word:

```
addPost(value: string){
    this.postList.push(new PostObject(value, false));
}
```

The object can't be seen in database. But when I tried with an object literal, it worked:

```
addPost(value: string){
    this.postList.push({
      text: value,
      isLiked: false
    });
}
```

PostObject class:

```
export class PostObject {

    comment = [];

    constructor(text: string, isLiked: boolean){}

}
```

So what is the difference between two methods above? Is there a way I could use a constructor to create and send objects to database?

Comment: Could you show the PostObject code? Did you try to use something like this JSON.stringify(new PostObject(value, false));

Comment: @CristianoAndalóTenuta I updated the question. I tried JSON.stringify and it worked but there was only the "comment" field in the object. When I defined "text" and "isLiked" fields out side the constructor, they were both included in the JSON string. Maybe I can't use typescript shortcut syntax here.

Comment: Check my answer. I had to post there because the link length is too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

But you still can use the "shortcut" syntax if you use public or private keyword. I did some tests on typescript playground and it worked just fine!

Take a look:

```
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20PostObject%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20comment%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(private%20text%3A%20string%2C%20private%20isLiked%3A%20boolean)%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20post%20%3D%20new%20PostObject(%22Test%22%2Ctrue)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20button%20%3D%20document.createElement('button')%3B%0D%0Abutton.textContent%20%3D%20%22Post%22%3B%0D%0Abutton.onclick%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(JSON.stringify(post))%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adocument.body.appendChild(button)%3B
```